# How to connect to a derby database in NetBeans?

Tags: java, database, netbeans, derby

I have created a project with a derby database on other computer and sent it to myself. Now I can't connect to the database.

Comment: Use this link https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html

Answer (score 3):

The Derby documentation contains an excellent set of tutorials to help you get started:

```
http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/getstart/
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using java Code to Connect to the Database from your programme using Net beans tool and Java.

Kindly Check

1.Make sure your User Name and Password are Connect .

2.Ping the DB port  from command Line from the other system from where you are 
connecting the Database.If you are not able to connect/Ping the DB it means either your port is not open or not responding.

3.You can also manually connect to the Derby database from the Net beans tool by following the below Link.

***Use Below Link***

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html

**Check Connection String of the Code**

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
String myDb = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/HWtrial";
Connection DBconn = DriverManager.getConnection(myDb, "","");
```